# ¿Cómo indicar diferentes decimales en diferentes filas en kable, manteniendo la coma como separador decimal?

Tags: r, formato

Tengo una tabla que quiero presentar en la que los valores de algunas filas deberían tener decimales, y los de otras no. Adicionalmente, me gustaría mantener la coma como separador decimal. Parece ser que puedo cumplir con una de las condiciones por vez, pero no con las dos juntas, al menos usando kableExtra: usar formatC para establecer el número de decimales transforma los valores en caracter, y ya no puedo indicar la coma como separador decimal. ¿Existe alguna forma más o menos sencilla de lograrlo? Aquí dejo un mínimo ejemplo:

````
---
title: "kble"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---
```{r global, include=FALSE}

library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(kableExtra)
library(janitor)

dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]%>% as.data.frame()%>%
  mutate(categoria = ifelse(disp<200,"1","0"))

```

Title...
===================================== 
Inputs {.sidebar data-width=400}
-------------------------------------
```{r cars}

filtered_data <- dt %>%
    filter(cyl==6)

number <-table(filtered_data$cyl)%>% as.data.frame()%>%rename("N" = Freq)

percent_cat_1 <- addmargins(table(filtered_data$cyl, filtered_data$`categoria`), 2)
percent_cat_12 <-as.data.frame.matrix(percent_cat_1) %>%
  mutate(`Percent cat 1` = round((`1`)/Sum*100,1))%>%
  select(-`1`,-`0`,-`Sum`)
percent_cat_1<- tibble::rownames_to_column(percent_cat_12, "Var1")

final_table <- number %>%
    left_join(percent_cat_1)%>%
    t()%>%as.data.frame()%>%
      row_to_names(row_number =1)

final_table[1] <- lapply(final_table[1], as.numeric) 

final_table%>%
    knitr::kable(format.args = list(decimal.mark = ',', big.mark = "."),
                caption = "Title",
                align = "ccc"
                )%>%
   kable_styling("striped","hover",full_width = F)

```
````

La fila N no debería mostrar decimales, pero la  "Percent cat 1" sí. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El formato de representación aplica a todos los elementos de un vector, y lo que estarías buscando es un formato condicional, si el número tiene o no decimales corresponderá mostrarlos o no. La función base `format()` que se usa en este caso, no contempla esta funcionalidad (de hecho no sé si es una buena idea representar los números de esta forma), si alguno de los elementos del vector tiene decimales, se muestran estos en todos los casos.

Lo que podrías hacer es formatear los números antes que lo haga `kable`. Por ejemplo así:

```
formateo_numeros <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x == as.integer(x),
         format(round(x, 0), nsmall=0, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ","),
         format(round(x, 2), nsmall=2, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ","))
}

n <- c(3, 66.7, 1500.3, 8000)
formateo_numeros(n)

[1] "    3"    "   66,70" "1.500,30" "8.000"
```

En este caso, un numérico sin decimales lo mostramos sin estos y los que lo tuvieran se muestran hasta 2. Es importante notar el uso de `round()` por que `format()` no miente en cuanto a los decimales, si hay uno con 3, el formato final tendrá 3 decimales, `nsmall=2` solo especifica el número mínimo de decimales.

En tu caso sería agregar esta conversión de la columna:

```
final_table %>%
    mutate(`6` = formateo_numeros(`6`)) %>% 
    knitr::kable(caption = "Title",
                 align = "ccc"
                 )%>%
   kable_styling("striped","hover",full_width = F)
```